# Create HTML and CSS for WPF WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, html, css, wpf, webbrowser-control

OK, so I'm building an application similar to the Battle.Net's launcher :) Tabs for multiple applications and I would have liked to add a "dynamic content area" where I could post news and stuff. Therefore I placed a WebBrowser there, set a width and a height and proceeded to create a static HTML file.

I am aware that WPF's measure unit is is not the pixel. Therefore, when creating the CSS for the HTML, I multiplied the WebBrowser's dimensions by 1.33 and used that for my HTML's body width and height. And it looked good on my work monitor. When I got home, surprise! Apparently my monitor works at a higher DPI value, therefore the image I had there was larger than the browser window, the text was way too big, etc. I did try switching to EM as a unit, but still no luck.

So, how can I create a webpage that will fit all kinds of DPI settings? Seeing as I can't really get the monitor DPI values (not reliably, as far as I have been able to read). Is it possible?

The other possibility that I have considered is to create a placeholder for an image and some text (WPF controls that is) and populate them from the server, but I may want to change the layout at some point, etc, therefore this doesn't really help me too much in the long run.

Comment: Put the `WebBrowser` in a [`ViewBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx).